# Partition HDD in two for BerryBoot

Tags: hard-drive, partition

I would like to know if it is possible to partition a hard drive in two and use one partition as a BerryBoot OS and the other as a normal external NTFS hard drive.

I want to use one part of the HDD for OSMC and the other to store my media on but also want to be able to plug HDD in my windows PC to copy, move or delete media files.

Comment: I assume you want to boot the PI directly from USB as well?  Have you done that before?  Have you used berryboot before?  You do know that if you do this then you will need to shut down the Pi to connect the HDD to your laptop?

Comment: Yes i am using berry boot now. And yes the pi will shut down then i will conect hdd to my pc to edit my media files. Thanx for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible.  One way to do it is to install berryboot on the whole drive, use it once so that the script to fill the hard disk is run and then resize (shrink) the second partition to create space for the third partition for NTFS.  Two partitions are needed for berryboot (or Raspbian, etc) with one being the boot partition and the other being the data partition.

If you are already booting the Raspberry PI from USB then you will know this but you will also need to edit the file /boot/cmdline.txt to point to the correct partition where the berryboot files are stored.  Typically this is /dev/mmcblk0p2 but if you are booting from USB it might be /dev/sda2.

Comment: I found a way.... i used berry boot and instaled osmc to a 16gb flash drive i then cloned the flash drive to my hard drive with no expansion and then repartitioned the remaining 800gb as a ntsf. Pluged hard drive into rpi with same sd card as was in with usb flash drive booted up and it works perfectly... can this couse any problems in the long run. Like the 16 gb ia to small for all the data.

Comment: @ImmanuelFerdinandDeBeer Please move your comment with the solution to an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.